# Laravel login on mobile without password: "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'"

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, mobile

When I login, I get this error.

LoginController.php

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('mobile');

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

    // User doesn't exist, create a new one
    $user = User::create($credentials);

    Auth::login($user);

    return redirect()->route('home');       
}
```

This error occurred at the following line:

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
```

And

I have a field, the `mobile`, (and without password) in both the registration form and the login form.

How can I design the form in such a way that if the mobile number is present in the user table database, it will login. If it doesn't exist, create it.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('mobile');
    $credentials['password'] = 'default_password';

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

    // User doesn't exist, create a new one
    $user = User::create($credentials);

    Auth::login($user);

    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

I want to login without a password only on mobile.

Comment: It might be helpful if we could see the `User` model and the structure of the table it's based on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel expects a field named `password` for it's `Auth::attempt()` method and when you do `$user = User::create($credentials);`, if your `users` table does not have a password field you will get an error thrown.

You could use another way to login your user such as `Auth::login()` or `Auth::loginUsingId()` to bypass that.

Assuming your user table looks like this:

```
+------------+
| users      |
+------------+
| id (pk)    |
| mobile     |
| timestamps |
+------------+
```

```php
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $mobile = $request->mobile;

    $user = User::firstOrCreate(['mobile' => $mobile]);

    Auth::login($user);

    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

You can even add a bit of validation by using the `validate()` method on the request.

```php
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->validate(['mobile' => ['required']]);

    $user = User::firstOrCreate($data);

    Auth::login($user);

    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

This will throw a ValidationException that should render nicely on the view if you're using the `@error` blade directive